# Javascript forloop change to lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Need to change javascript code to lodash

```
var templates = {
"category": {
    "findByName": {
        "method": "generic",
            "settings": {
            "baseURL": "some2"
        }
    }
},
"product": {
    "findByPartNumber": {
        "method": "generic",
            "settings": {
            "baseURL": "some1"
        }
    },
    "findByUniqueId": {
        "method": "generic",
        "settings": {
            "baseURL": "some1"
        }
    }
}
};


for ( var index in templates) {
    var module = templates[index];

    for ( var fileIndex in module) {

        if (module[fileIndex].method) {

            var dsSettings = module[fileIndex].settings;
           console.log(dsSettings)
        }
    }
}
```

result :

```
{ baseURL: 'some2' }
{ baseURL: 'some1' }
{ baseURL: 'some1' }
```

Lodash code:

```
_.forEach(templates, function(n, key) {
    var v = _.pluck(_.filter(n), 'settings');

    console.log(v);
});
```

result:

```
[ { baseURL: 'some2' } ]
[ { baseURL: 'some1' }, { baseURL: 'some1' } ]
```

I am looking for object result in lodash code as given above. Please suggest

Comment: What's the issue? Do you want the same output in both cases?

Comment: yes I am looking for same output for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an one-liner:

```
settings = _(templates).map(_.values).flatten().pluck('settings').value()
```

```js
var templates = {
    "category": {
        "findByName": {
            "method": "generic",
            "settings": {
                "baseURL": "some2"
            }
        }
    },
    "product": {
        "findByPartNumber": {
            "method": "generic",
            "settings": {
                "baseURL": "some1"
            }
        },
        "findByUniqueId": {
            "method": "generic",
            "settings": {
                "baseURL": "some1"
            }
        }
    }
};


settings = _(templates).map(_.values).flatten().pluck('settings').value()
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(settings,0,3));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: still result coming in array of object [ { baseURL: 'some2' },
  { baseURL: 'some1' },
  { baseURL: 'some1' } ]

Comment: @Elankeeran: this is what you want, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `_.flatten`

```
var target = [];

_.forEach(templates, function(n, key) {
    target.push(_.pluck(_.filter(n), 'settings'));
});

target = _.flatten(target);
```

http://jsbin.com/nedeviyiko/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Glad to have helped :) give it a check when you're able ;)

Comment: In that case, `_.map` might be cleaner: `var target = _.flatten(_.map(templates, function(n) { return target.push(_.pluck(_.filter(n), 'settings')); }));`

Comment: Not sure I understand why that's cleaner. It's using flatten, map, pluck, *and* filter. It also doesn't work.

Comment: @FelixKling output [ 4, 5 ] but this not expected result.

Comment: Oops, I forget to remove the target push stuff (writing code in comments is hard :P): `var target = _.flatten(_.map(templates, function(n) { return _.pluck(n, 'settings'); })); `. It just moves from an imperative style to a more functional style. (I also don't think `_.filter` is necessary).

Answer (score 1):

pluck and filter in lodash will always return arrays, so if you console.log the output of those functions you will always end up with an array instead of just a list of objects. You need to iterate through the array contained in v and console.log each of those values.

One note: why are you using _.filter? pluck should not mutate the underlying object so there is no reason to filter or clone the object n

Comment: Thanks... i just changes the code as _.forEach(templates, function(n) {
    _.forEach(_.pluck(n, 'settings'), function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

I did like this.. is there any better way to solve this?

```
_.forEach(templates, function(n) {
    _.forEach(_.pluck(_.filter(n), 'settings'), function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    });
});
```

Comment: but result given as array object and LOC is more I am looking for best and clear code with less line

Comment: Your `result` code given in the initial question *is an object* and you were asking how to achieve the same thing. Perhaps your question is just confusing...

Comment: still i am looking for better answer for 1 line code in lodash